# Plot doesn't accept input directly from DSolveValue

Tags: plotting

Mathematica newbie working his way through Hastings' introductory text.

```
DSolveValue[{y'[x]==1,y[0]==0},y[x],x]
```

returns a solution of `x`. So far so good.

However, if I try;

```
Plot[DSolveValue[{y'[x]==1,y[0]==0},y[x],x],{x,-1,1}]
```

I get no plot (the axes draw but that's it) and the error message;
"DSolveValue: The variable specification is not valid."

On the otherhand,

```
soln=DSolveValue[{y'[x]==1,y[0]==0},y[x],x];
Plot[soln,{x,-1,1}]
```

works.

Why?

many thanks

Comment: This is certainly a dupe, but in a nutshell: the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot[]` necessitates special handling: `Plot[DSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1, y[0] == 0}, y[x], x] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the speedy response JM.